# Extract non intersected element from a string vector in R

Tags: r, string, vector, intersect

I have 2 string vectors, and I have intersected them in order to get the intersected string vector, but now, I need to get the 2 other string vectors without the intersected elements.

That is, `vector.1` without `intersected.vector` elements, and `vector.2` without `intersected.vector` elements. How can I do that?

Comment: You can try `v3 <- intersect(v1, v2); v1[!v1 %in% v3]; v2[!v2 %in% v3]`

Comment: Also `setdiff(v1, v2)` and `setdiff(v2, v1)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this simple example illustrates what you are asking for:

```
vector.1 <- LETTERS[1:4]
vector.2 <- LETTERS[3:6]

> vector.1
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
> vector.2
[1] "C" "D" "E" "F"

intersected.vector <- intersect(vector.1, vector.2)
> intersected.vector
[1] "C" "D"

new_vec1 <- vector.1[-which(vector.1 %in% intersected.vector)]
> new_vec1
[1] "A" "B"

new_vec2 <- vector.2[-which(vector.2 %in% intersected.vector)]
> new_vec2
[1] "E" "F"
```